# Cannot run Android 8.0 VD on MacOS high sierra

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, macos-high-sierra

I need to use `Android 8.0` virtual device. So I have installed android studio (`3.1.3`) and created a VD. But it is not working. Do you know why?

**Note:** I restarted the MacBook after `HAXM` installation.

Up to this level, it's loaded:

[image]

It shows this warning. I don't think it is an issue for this. Your thoughts?

`Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release`

This is my **MacBook configuration**:

[image]

This is the **Android virtual device**:

[image]

[image]

**SDK:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem on my Atari 65XE ...

Comment: Did you find out the solution? @Selvin

Comment: Yeah ... I gave my 65XE to museum and bought new computer. UG(unrestricted guest) is required for emulator ... and Core 2 duo doesn't support it ...

Comment: What is the minimum MacBook should I purchase? Configuration or Year? @Selvin

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace in Boot Options "Quick boot" to "Cold boot". As the message error mentionned , quick boot seems to be not supported on your machine (Macbook pro late 2009 seems old for that).

Quick Boot is a feature introduced in December 2017 that speed up the emulator startup

Comment: Still not working. I think this is the issue: https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/30